# How to select fields from related tables in dreamfactory

Tags: select, relationship, virtual, dreamfactory

I am playing with the DreamFactory Schema and API Docs. Within the Schema i add a "Virtual Relationship". Now in API Docs i put the name of the Virtual Relationship in related, on execute everthing is fine. I'll get the fields from the related table. But i dont need all fields from the joined table. How to select only the fields i need? I try to add `"name_of_related.field"` under `"fields"`.

> Error:
>
> "message": "Invalid field requested: fe_users_by_fe_user_id.username"

Answer (score 2):

add `<relation_name>.fields=fieldname1,fieldname2`

in my case:

```
/api/v2/myservice/_table/mytable?fields=uid,tstamp&related=fe_users_by_fe_user_id&fe_users_by_fe_user_id.fields=username
```